# How to fit an image to the UV Editor window's borders?

Tags: interface, image

I try to place the rendered image inside the *UV Editor* window so it fits its borders precisely. Unfortunatelly it isn't possible using a **Mouse Wheel**. Are there any ways to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To fill the screen press the <kbd>F</kbd> key

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way how to do it. There are two methods:

1. While in the UV Editor window, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then press the Middle Mouse Button and move the mouse horizontally or vertically. You may now manually fit the image to the borders of the window.
   [image]
2. While in the UV Editor window, press the <kbd>F</kbd> button. An image will automatically fit the window borders perfectly.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have already suggested, if your keyboard has a <kbd>Home</kbd> button, you can press that too, which will zoom the image to 100% size (if it's smaller than the panel) or to the size of the panel (if it's larger).